# jQuery: Getting the two last list items?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors, traversal

I want to apply a special class to the two last list items in an unordered list with jQuery. Like this:

```
<ul>
<li>Lorem</li>
<li>ipsum</li>
<li>dolor</li>
<li class="special">sit</li>
<li class="special">amet</li>
</ul>
```

How to? Should I use :eq somehow?

Thanks in advance

Pontus

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Another approach, using [andSelf](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/andSelf) and [prev](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/prev):

```
$('ul li:last-child').prev('li').andSelf().addClass("special");
```

Comment: andSelf() was deprecated since jQuery 1.8 and removed in 3.0

Answer (score 51):

You can use function [slice](http://api.jquery.com/slice/). It is very flexible.

```
$('ul li').slice(-2).addClass("special");
```

Comment: I wouldn't consider this "native".

Answer (score 5):

```
var items = $('ul li')
var last_two = items.filter('li:gt('+ items.length-3 +')')
last_two.addClass('special');
```

Comment: alternatively: items.slice(items.length - 2).addClass('special')

Comment: Thanks a lot, but what do I then do with the variable "last_two"?

Comment: last_two.addClass("special");

Answer (score 3):

```
$(function(){

  $("li:gt("+($("li").length-3)+")").addClass("special");

});
```