# How to find the last two elements with the same class in a div and assign them a class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div id="main-container">
    <div class="box">apple</div>
    <div class="box">bus</div>
    <div class="box">cattle</div>
    <div class="box">dog</div>
    <div class="box">eggplant</div>
    <div class="box">fox</div>
    <div class="box">goat</div>
</div>
```

How do I find the last two ".box" within "#main-container" and then assign them with a specific class?

Comment: You may want to provide some context. There may be a better way to do what you're doing.

Comment: Maybe answer to this question will help: [jQuery: Getting the two last list items?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257233/jquery-getting-the-two-last-list-items)

Comment: @PitaJ basically a template is generating divs with the class 'box' and I have no control over it. However, I do know the last two .box I need not to show. So what I need to two is find them specifically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `slice` method to get the last 2 child elements & then add a specific class you wanted.

```
$('#main-container .box').slice(-2).addClass('someclass')
```

Comment: You should have said you wanted a jQuery answer.

Comment: I don't remember the tags saying jQuery, or I would have given a jQuery answer. Anyway, I guess both answers can be useful in the future.

Comment: I don't think he added the jQuery tag until after I answered.

Answer (score 4):

You can select the last 2 boxes with the css selector `nth-last-child`:

`.box:nth-last-child(-n+2) {}`

http://jsfiddle.net/ekDbA/

browser support IE9+ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-child?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2F%3Anth-last-child

Answer (score 1):

For your specific question...

```
var main = document.getElementById('main-container');
var boxes = main.getElementsByClassName('box');

boxes[boxes.length - 2].className += ' a-class'; // 2nd to last
boxes[boxes.length - 1].className += ' a-class'; // last
```

As PitaJ said, though, there may be a better way to achieve your actual goal, if you would convey it.