# upgrading from javascript to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following javascript function that I call on body onload. But I want to change the javascript function into jQuery statements and call them directly inside of the document.ready() function.

```
function ChangeSomeStyles(){
    //hide the last two links of TopNav
    var container = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];
    var lastchild = container.lastChild;    
    var secondlastchild = container.childNodes[container.childNodes.length-2];
    lastchild.style.display = 'none';
    secondlastchild.style.display = 'none';
    //Show TopNav as it is hidden by default in CSS
    document.getElementById('WrapperTopNav').style.display = 'block';
    //if homepage, set Footer width to 960
    if ((document.URL === "http://testsiteqa/Pages/Default.aspx") || (document.URL === "http://testsitetf/Pages/Default.aspx") || (document.URL === "http://testsite/Pages/Default.aspx")){
        document.getElementById('Footer').style.width = '960px';
    }
}
```

======================================================>

```
$(document).ready(){
  $('ul li:last-child').hide();
  //how do I get the second last li?
  $('#WrapperTopNav').css('display','block');
  if ((document.URL === "http://testsiteqa/Pages/Default.aspx") || (document.URL === "http://testsitetf/Pages/Default.aspx") || (document.URL === "http://testsite/Pages/Default.aspx")){
     $('#Footer').css('width','960px');             
  }    
});
```

How do I get the second last menu item to hide? Is the above conversion look about right?

Comment: Hrm... personally, I'd say Vanilla JS => jQuery is a downgrade. But that's just, like, my opinion.

Comment: What's the question/problem/issue?

Comment: WHen you do downvote please let me know why, so I can improve my questions???

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: Getting the two last list items?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257233/jquery-getting-the-two-last-list-items)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by using `.eq()`

Try,

```
  var cache = $('ul li');
  cache.eq(cache.length-1).hide();  //last one
  cache.eq(cache.length-2).hide();  //second one from the last
```

or you can use `.prev()` to get the previous sibling of the last li element,

```
  var cache = $('ul li:last-child').hide(); //last one
  cache.prev().hide(); //second one from the last
```

### [Conceptual DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/sZs58/)

Or as A.wolf suggested we can access the collection reversely by providing index in negative,

```
  var cache = $('ul li');
  cache.eq(-1).hide();  //last one
  cache.eq(-2).hide();  //second one from the last
```

Comment: @A.Wolff hmm, yes.. just now read the document regarding that. will update accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I would use this:

```
$('ul > li:gt(-3)').hide();
```

That will select the last two `li` that are direct descendants of the `ul`  and hide them.