# find last 2 children using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My HTML is like this

```html
<div class="accordion_example2 smk_accordion acc_with_icon"> 
    <div class="accordion_in">
        <div class="acc_head accordian-title-white">
            <div class="acc_icon_expand"></div>
            19714320
        </div>
        <div class="acc_content accordian-content-white" style="display: none;">
            <ul>
             
                <li>
                    Break Load (kg) 6.05
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion_in">
        <div class="acc_head accordian-title-blue">
            <div class="acc_icon_expand"></div>
            mere test tekst …
        </div>
        <div class="acc_content accordian-content" style="display: none;">
            <ul>
              
               
                <li>
                    Break Load (kg)
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion_in">
        <div class="acc_head accordian-title-white">
            <div class="acc_icon_expand"></div>
            test tekst
        </div>
        <div class="acc_content accordian-content-white" style="display: none;">
            <ul>
               
                <li>
                    Break Load (kg)
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to find the last two `accordion_in` elements and remove its child element `accordian-content` from it. How can I achieve this through Jquery?
My expected out put is like this

```html
<div class="accordion_example2 smk_accordion acc_with_icon"> 
    <div class="accordion_in">
        <div class="acc_head accordian-title-white">
            <div class="acc_icon_expand"></div>
            19714320
        </div>
        <div class="acc_content accordian-content-white" style="display: none;">
            <ul>
             
                <li>
                    Break Load (kg) 6.05
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion_in">
        <div class="acc_head accordian-title-blue">
            <div class="acc_icon_expand"></div>
            mere test tekst …
        </div>
        
    </div>
    <div class="accordion_in">
        <div class="acc_head accordian-title-white">
            <div class="acc_icon_expand"></div>
            test tekst
        </div>
        
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please include the attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. Thanks!

Comment: dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257233/jquery-getting-the-two-last-list-items

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948152/select-last-5-elements-with-jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this : You can use `.slice()` to get last two elements and then remove `accordian-content` div from it.

```js
$(function(){
  $('div.accordion_example2 .accordion_in').slice("-2").find(".accordian-content").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion_example2 smk_accordion acc_with_icon"> 
    <div class="accordion_in">
        <div class="acc_head accordian-title-white">
            <div class="acc_icon_expand"></div>
            19714320
        </div>
        <div class="acc_content accordian-content-white" style="display: none;">
            <ul>
             
                <li>
                    Break Load (kg) 6.05
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion_in">
        <div class="acc_head accordian-title-blue">
            <div class="acc_icon_expand"></div>
            mere test tekst …
        </div>
        <div class="acc_content accordian-content" style="display: none;">
            <ul>
              
               
                <li>
                    Break Load (kg)
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion_in">
        <div class="acc_head accordian-title-white">
            <div class="acc_icon_expand"></div>
            test tekst
        </div>
        <div class="acc_content accordian-content-white" style="display: none;">
            <ul>
               
                <li>
                    Break Load (kg)
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Can use `:gt()` selector and by using a negative value it will work from the end. Requires jQuery 1.8+

```
$('.accordion_in:gt(-3)').find('.acc-content').remove();
```

reference: [:gt() selector docs](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)

Comment: Or in one selector: `$('.accordion_in:gt(-3) > .acc_content').remove();`

Answer (score -2):

You can do this by using de `:nth-last-of-type` selector

`$(".class:nth-last-of-type(-n+2)")` selects the last 2 .class elements.

In your case:

```
$(".accordion_in:nth-last-of-type(-n+2)").children(".accordian-content").remove();
```

Or use find:
    $(".accordion_in:nth-last-of-type(-n+2)").find(".accordian-content").remove();

**Edit**: Had to be -n+2 instead of 2.

Comment: actually, nope. nth means every nth, and not the last nth. last in this selector just means its counting from the end instead of from the beginning

Comment: actually your edit works: http://jsfiddle.net/9m0m8hcd/ but you do know that this function wasnt intended to do that? Slice definately is the better option to go!